# How to get arbitrary data set in a different event handler on the bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to figure out how to get data stored via jQuery's `.data()` method, between two event handlers for the modal.

I am working on a form builder, where the user is provided with a menu of *addable* items to the form (namely rows, inputs, textareas, dropdowns, panels, etc.) and upon clicking on any item, a modal is shown enlisting the various settings/options for the item.

**The Scenario:** The user clicks on an element type and the modal for the settings for that element type shows up. Now the user is provided with the set of options/settings for the particular item (*e.g. the title/name of the element, it's width, color, etc.*).

Suppose, the user clicks on the button from the menu to add the panel and the modal appears.

[image]
 Then, he/she enters the title for the panel, and *on change event* of the `input`, its value is stored as such:

```
$(panelModal).on('change', 'input', function () {
    $(this).data('value', $(this).val());
}) /** ... */
```

**The Poblem:** The events registered on the modal are in the following sequence:

```
this.addPanel = function () {
    $(panelModal).on('change', 'input', function(){
          //logic for storing the input's value
          $(this).data('value', $(this).val());
    }).on('click', '.addPanelButton', function () {
         //logic when the panel is set to be added to the DOM (omitted).
         //the data set in the first handler is an empty object if logged here
    }).modal();
  }
};
```

Basically what I want to achieve is that the arbitrary data stored on the *input* in the first handler, to be accessed *in the second handler*, where the panel is about to be added to the DOM, so that I set the title of the panel with the provided value.

But the problem is that the two event handlers *aren't aware of each others existence*, meaning if something was done in one of the two, the other is totally unaware of it (as it seems).

***So, what would be the proper way of registering the events on the modal, or if the one specified is correct, how do I get the arbitrary data from the modal?***

Answer (score 0):

Can we re-write your code as follows:

```
    this.addPanel = function () {
        $(panelModal).on('change', 'input', function(){
              //logic for storing the input's value
              $(panelModal).data('title_value', $(this).val());
        }).on('click', '.addPanelButton', function () {
             //logic when the panel is set to be added to the DOM (omitted).
             //the data set in the first handler is an empty object if logged here

             var title_value = $(panelModal).data('title_value');
        }).modal();
      }
    };
```

Instead of attaching the value to each separate field, can its OK to attach it to `$(panelModal)`. By this way you can fetch required data any time.